# Jquery .append() & Html.Helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, jquery, append

Is there any way to put html.helper inside a .append() function.

```
success: function (html) { $("#Resultaatsgebied").append(' <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.RG1)<ul id="Concretisering" class="subList"><li>@Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.RG1sub1)</li></ul>@Html.ActionLink("+", "index", null, new { id = "addConcretisering" })</li>'); }
```

This works, but just as a string, not as a control

**EDIT:**

This works now, but the actionlink who is generated does not.
I have the same actionlink default in my view, and there it works.
But for the generated one, I think he just does not execute the ajax call?

Comment: it is bceause this is executed in the client side, not in the server

Comment: so it can't be fixed?

Comment: I don't know about asp.net, but i think it has a fragment concept where you can create a html fragment and return it to client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is in a razor view, you can put into brackets your razor code like this :

```
success: function (html) { 
    $("#Resultaatsgebied").append(' <li>@(Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.RG1))<ul id="Concretisering" class="subList"><li>@(Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.RG1sub1))</li></ul>@(Html.ActionLink("+", "index", null, new { id = "addConcretisering" }))</li>'); 
}
```

Comment: did this work for anyone?? doesn't work for me on MVC 5 razor (cshtml)

Comment: I tried it with MVC 5 and does not seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC 5 razor or newest versions, This quota --> **`'`** not working anymore. Therefore, use **( ` )** mark to do your work

```
success: function (html) {     
   $("#Resultaatsgebied").append(` 
      <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.RG1)    
           <ul id="Concretisering" class="subList">     
                <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.RG1sub1)</li>   
           </ul>      
           @Html.ActionLink("+", "index", null, new { id = "addConcretisering" })    
      </li>
  `);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do that in pure Javascript. Why don't you set the returned data from AJAX as HTML and you can set it for any div you want. For example in your case:

```
$("#Resultaatsgebied").html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a better concatenation like this (*not sure but you can try*):

```
success: function (html) { 
    $("#Resultaatsgebied").append(
          '<li>' + @Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.RG1) + 
          '<ul id="Concretisering" class="subList"><li>' + 
             @Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.RG1sub1) + 
          '</li></ul>' + 
             @Html.ActionLink("+", "index", null, new { id = "addConcretisering" }) + 
          '</li>'); 
}
```